# call javascript function through dropdown list

Tags: javascript, onclick, onchange, dropdown

How can I go about calling this function through a dropdown menu and the for loop catching all data and not just the last? I've tried some things and all I would get is the last bit of information. Thank you in advance.

```
<script>


            function hey(){
            for (i = 1; i < radio.length; i++){

document.write('<div class="dell"><img class="dell3" align="left" src=images/'  + radio[i].image + '> <div class="space"> <font size="4">' + i + '. &nbsp;' + radio[i].name + '</font></br><font color="silver">' + radio[i].category + '</br>' + radio[i].address + '</br>' + radio[i].citystate + '</font></div> </div>');
                }
                }

</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Where radio coming from?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add class to every item of `<select>`(`<option>`). 
Get nodelist of option-elements:

```
const optionList = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
```

And for each element add event listener with desired function:

```
optionList.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('event', fucntion(){}));
```

Edit your code a bit because it's confusing to scroll.